# Refrigerator clearance and heat in summer

Tags: appliances

I'm looking at new refrigerators and apparently they all need some clearance around the back, sides, and top for airflow. According to my current understanding, this is so the heat from within the refrigerator can be removed into the outside air, and the clearance room allows that hot air to go out away from the vicinity from the refrigerator, hence keeping it cool.

But does airflow and clearance matter at all in a hot summer? For example if indoor temperatures reach 40 degrees Celsius, then whether there is any clearance becomes pointless correct? Because by then the hot air is everywhere so technically it cannot be removed. Will a refrigerator operating for months on end in a 40 degree Celsius environment malfunction then?

Comment: A fridge is an air conditioner.  It takes heat inside and pushes it out.  The clearance is to allow that air to escape, it does not matter what the air temperature is, unless above what the fridge or any device is suppose to work in.  It will also have a minimum temperature.  Check the working min and max temperature of the fridge to see if 40C is too warm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect, **VERY incorrect**.

In hot summer weather, the fridge is rejecting heat at a temperature hotter than whatever the temperature around it is. So if it's 40°C in general, it's probably 50°C or more at the hot parts of the fridge.

Cooling air flow is **VERY important** when the "cool" air is 40°C, as you need *a lot more air* to take the heat away than you do when the cooling air is 20°C

If the fridge is not rated to run at 40°C ambient, then you'll likely kill it anyway. But you'll certainly kill it faster if you choke off the airflow. Picking a fridge at random I find an operating temperature range of 13-43°C (55-110°F) - if the fridge will be used in a particularly hot location, you can search for ones with higher operating temperature ranges before selecting one to purchase. Or, you may need to air-condition the space the refrigerator is in, with an air-conditioner rated for the temperatures experienced.

Comment: I see...so I'm interested in a fridge that specs 10cm airflow space on top, and 2cm airflow space on the sides. My kitchen layout only gives 1.2 cm on top, and 8 cm on each side. Would the wider side berths make up for the much smaller top airflow space? Thanks.